# Можно ли собирать id пользователей Odnoklassniki на сайте?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, odnoklassniki-api

Собирать id пользователей vk можно и уже есть подобные сервисы. А можно ли таким образом узнавать id пользователей ok.ru, которые заходили на мой сайт?
[пример скрипта для вк](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1G1ksNI6PybWXlqdU9UYV90SmM&usp=sharing).

Comment: Собирать id пользователей vk нельзя. А сервисы, которые это делают - используют дырки в системе. И в целом это, по-сути, преступление, т.к. собираются не только идентификаторы, но и информация пользователя без его ведома

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, судя по скрипту, он собирает не всех, у тех кто поставил на странице лайк, и судя по API, vk отдает ID всех поставивших. Хотя я мог и ошибиться в скрипте.

Comment: @NikolaTesla нет, вы не правы....он собирает у всех кто на странице...точнее кто хоть раз кликнул в любую область на странице........просто виджет не виден пользователю .....пользователь не знает, что в это время на странице что-то подобное есть. А значит любые подобные маневры - неправонамеренные

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я вижу что на почту отправляется информация от API функции VK likes.getList, то есть, тех кто поставил лайки. То есть, сам скрипт ничего не собирает. А вот ставит ли он лайки автоматически, я поленился разбираться :)

Comment: @NikolaTesla Скрипт и собирает....в общем уж поверьте на слово, что фактически то, что там описано - факт нарушений пав пользователя.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на чем основано Ваше утверждение, что скрипт сам собирает? Имя файла, строку в коде укажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя делать ни то, ни другое. Так как это сбор инфы пользователей без их ведома, то это в своем роде, преступление. Вы сможете собрать айди только в том случае, если пользователь войдет на Ваш сайт с помощью ок. Других вариантов на сей день пока нету.